# Возникновение ошибки: "NoneType" object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, sqlite3

Мне нужно добавить мультиязыность в своего бота. При запросе значения из базы данных возникает ошибка: `"NoneType" object is not iterable`. Сколько бы я не пытался, решить ее не могу.

```py
def start(message):
    get_language = get_user_language(user_id = message.from_user.id)
    if get_language == "RU":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет!")
```

```py
@ensure_connection
def get_user_language(conn, user_id: int):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT language FROM user_language WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id, ))
    (res, ) = c.fetchone()
    return res
```

Ошибка, которая возникает:

```bsh
user@user-pc:~/telegramBOT$ python3 code.py 
2020-08-19 16:31:58,439 (util.py:68 WorkerThread1) ERROR - TeleBot: "TypeError occurred, args=("'NoneType' object is not iterable",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 62, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "code.py", line 14, in start
    get_language = get_user_language(user_id = message.from_user.id)
  File "/home/user/telegramBOT/database.py", line 7, in inner
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/telegramBOT/database.py", line 48, in get_user_language
    (res, ) = c.fetchone()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 49, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop = True)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 427, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 451, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 111, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 62, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "code.py", line 14, in start
    get_language = get_user_language(user_id = message.from_user.id)
  File "/home/user/telegramBOT/database.py", line 7, in inner
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/telegramBOT/database.py", line 48, in get_user_language
    (res, ) = c.fetchone()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (ссылка `править` под вопросом). А так, проверьте что в `user_id` не находится `None`

Comment: @gil9red все, я добавил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, в таблице `user_language` не нашлось записи с `user_id`, поэтому `c.fetchone()` вернул `None`

Попробуйте так:

```
@ensure_connection
def get_user_language(conn, user_id: int):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT language FROM user_language WHERE user_id = ?", [user_id])
    result = c.fetchone()
    if result:
        return result[0]
    return "RU"  # Возвращаем язык бота по умолчанию
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все работает, но нужно удалить строчку `return "RU"`, ибо он будет получать только ответ - "RU".

Comment: @АрсенийТайко, пожалуйста :)